# Dealing with conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A programmer's programs are correct or buggy with equal probability $\frac{1}{2}$, independently. Three of his programs are randomly selected. Assume that one of the three is inspected at random, what is the probability $P$ that exactly one of the other two is buggy?

Why is it not $\frac{3}{7}$, removing the choice that all of them are correct?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the case that all of them are correct? It's just as likely as the other $7$ cases.

Comment: Inspection of one program does not change probabilities for the others.

Comment: Does that mean it's 4/8?

Comment: I would say $2/2^2$. But sure!